# group by and summarize with conditional date range aspect - dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, lubridate

*disclosure - this is my first SO question, my apologies if this is a repeat question but I have looked for a while now and have not found an answer to this particular scenario*

*R version: 3.4.2*

I want an efficient way of grouping data by a certain identifier and then summarize based on a condition - dynamically for each row. Specifically, group by ID and then sum how many instances another variable occurred (urgent visits) IF the other instance was within 1 year of the current row.

Here is an example of what the data looks like to start:

**Updated to include example of 2 urgent cases**

```
library(lubridate)
   > dat <- data.frame("ID" = c(6,6,6,7,7,10,11,11,11),
                      "Admit_Dt" = as.Date(c('2013-08-12', '2013-12-12', '2016-01-03','2011-04-01', '2011-09-20','2012-02-19','2014-06-24','2014-08-12','2014-09-01')), 
                      "Urgent" = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)) 
   > dat

| ID | Admit_Dt   | Urgent|
|  6 | 2013-08-12 |      1| 
|  6 | 2013-12-12 |      0|
|  6 | 2016-01-03 |      1|
|  7 | 2011-04-01 |      1|
|  7 | 2011-09-20 |      0|
| 10 | 2012-02-19 |      0|
| 11 | 2014-06-24 |      1|
| 11 | 2014-08-12 |      1|
| 11 | 2014-09-01 |      1|
```

I want to first group by ID and then sum how many urgent visits occurred within one year of each Admit_Dt for a given group.

This over complicated code below produces what I want but the dataset I am working with is very large and I this is pretty inefficient. I'm curious if there is a method using 'dplyr' to achieve what I am trying to do:

```
   > dat$Urgent_1yrSum <- unlist(sapply(1:length(unique(dat$ID)), function(i) {
    grouped <-  subset(dat, ID == unique(dat$ID)[i])
      output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(grouped), function(y){
    urgent_sum_1year <- sum(grouped[grouped$Admit_Dt < grouped$Admit_Dt[y] & grouped$Admit_Dt > (grouped$Admit_Dt[y] - dyears(1)), "Urgent"])
     }))
      return(output)
}
))

> dat
| ID | Admit_Dt   | Urgent| Urgent_1yrSum|
|  6 | 2013-08-12 |      1|          0|
|  6 | 2013-12-12 |      0|          1|
|  6 | 2016-01-03 |      1|          0|
|  7 | 2011-04-01 |      1|          0|
|  7 | 2011-09-20 |      0|          1|
| 10 | 2012-02-19 |      0|          0|
| 11 | 2014-06-24 |      1|          0|
| 11 | 2014-08-12 |      1|          1|
| 11 | 2014-09-01 |      1|          2|
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I was getting the error `Error in e1 + (-e2) : non-numeric argument to binary operator` when trying your code

Comment: I think that error came up because Admit_Dt was not structured as a date class in the example data. I have added 'as.Date' when creating the df.

Comment: are you sure your last row is correct? should it be admit_dt of 2014-09-01 instead?

Comment: updated! Sorry, making fake data is harder than asking the actual question haha.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get your code to work so I tried to see if I could get this to work. I first inner joined to get all combos of dates by ID. When you subtract them you can then use filter to see who received a visit within a year of each date and then `summarise`.

```
dat <- data.frame("ID" = c(6,6,6,7,7,10,11,11),
                  "Admit_Dt" = c('2013-08-12', '2013-12-12', '2016-01-03','2011-04-01', '2011-09-20','2012-02-19','2014-06-24','2014-08-12'), 
                  "Urgent" = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)


dat2 <- inner_join(dat,select(dat,ID,Admit_Dt,Urgent),by = "ID") %>% 
        #Inner Join by ID to get every combo of dates
        #Subtract dates from eachother 
        mutate(datediff = as.Date(Admit_Dt.x) - as.Date(Admit_Dt.y),
               ID = ID) %>%
        #get dates that occured within one year of visit
        #for each date
        filter(datediff > 0 & datediff <= 365) %>% 
        #group by person
        group_by(ID,Admit_Dt.x) %>% 
        #count urgent visits
       mutate(urgent_visits = max(Urgent.x,Urgent.y,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    summarise(vs = sum(urgent_visits))
#Join back on to df

dat3 <- left_join(dat,dat2,by = c("ID" = "ID", "Admit_Dt"="Admit_Dt.x"))
```

Comment: This gives the wrong count for `2011-09-20`. I think you have to keep the other copy of the `Urgent` column and then do a `max(Urgent.x, Urgent.y)` instead of `sum(Urgent)` since you want to check if either one of the two dates was an urgent visit. Or maybe a cumsum.. not sure since the example only ever goes up to one.

Comment: @strawberryBeef you are totally right, I switched to max and it gave the desired result

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike - with the sum update it works great! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using `dplyr`, list columns, and `purrr`. I'm assuming there are no duplicate `ID`s and `Admit_Dt`s otherwise I'm pretty sure this doesn't work right.

```
dat <- data.frame("ID" = c(6,6,6,7,7,10,11,11),
           "Admit_Dt" = c('2013-08-12', '2013-12-12', '2016-01-03','2011-04-01', '2011-09-20','2012-02-19','2014-06-24','2014-08-12'), 
           "Urgent" = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1), stringsAsFactors = F)


library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

isUrgentAndWithinYear <- function(urgent, date, date1){
     sum( urgent == 1 & abs(as.numeric(difftime(date, date1, units = "weeks"))) < 52)
} 

dat %>%
     mutate(Admit_Dt = ymd(Admit_Dt)) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(urgents = list(Urgent),
            admits = list(Admit_Dt)
            )%>% 
     group_by(ID, Admit_Dt) %>% 
     mutate(Urgent_1yrSum = map2_dbl(urgents, admits, ~ isUrgentAndWithinYear(.x, .y, Admit_Dt) )) %>% 
     mutate(Urgent_1yrSum = Urgent_1yrSum - Urgent) %>% 
     select(-urgents, -admits)
```